# Set of continuous function from a closed interval to real has a countable dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X = C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ be the metric space with uniform metric, then how to show that it has a countable dense subset?

It looks like Stone-Weistrass can construct a dense subset, but I am not sure how to contrsuct a subset that is also countable. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Weierstrass says polynomials are dense. Polynomials have coefficients, which are nothing but real numbers. And $\mathbb R$ has dense subsets of various kinds.

Comment: Awesome, just rational coef polynomials. Thank you @zhw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q^*$ be the set of polynomials $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ that have rational co-efficients. Observe that $Q^*$ is countable. Let $P^*$ be the set of all polynomials $p:[0,1]\to \mathbb R.$

For $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^np_jx^j\in P^*:\;$ Given $r>0,$ for $j=0,...,n$ take   $q_j\in  \mathbb Q$   such that $|p_j-q_j|<r/(n+1).$ Then for all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $$|p(x)-\sum_{j=0}^nq_jx^j|\leq \sum_{j=0}^n|p_j-q_j|\cdot |x^j|\leq\sum_{j=0}^n|p_j-q_j|<r.$$   So $Cl(Q^*)\supset P^*.$ So $$Cl(Q^*)=Cl(Cl(Q^*))\supset Cl(P^*)=C[0,1].$$

Remark. There are easier ways than the Weierstrass Theorem to find a countable dense subset of $C[0,1].$ Take  rationals $A_0,...,A_{n+1}$ with $A_0=0,$ $A_{n+1}=1,$ and $A_j<A_{j+1}$ for $0\leq j\leq n.$ Let $g\in C[0,1]$ where $g(A_j)$ is rational for $j=0,...,n+1,$ and $g$ is linear on  $[A_j,A_{j+1}]$ for $0\leq j\leq n.$

The set of all such $g$ (over all $n$ and all such $A_0,..., A_{n+1}$) is dense in $C[0,1].$ To prove it, use the uniform continuity of any $f\in C[0,1].$ That is $$\forall e>0\;\exists d>0\;\forall x,y\in [0,1]\;(|x-y|<d\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<e).$$